# What is 'use' here a noun or a verb?

Tags: grammar, meaning-in-context

What is 'use' here a noun or a verb and its meaning deriving from that?

> However, a proposal to change rules on land **use** threatens the city’s
>   quality of life, tourism economy and views of the Chesapeake, the
>   National Trust says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a noun in your sentence (land use) and it [means](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/use):

> Your use of something is the action or fact of your using it.

"A proposal" is the subject of your sentence and it needs a singular verb `(verb + s)`. The verb of your sentence is **"threatens"**.